# Finding an element array with certain different value in string array java

Tags: java, arrays

I have string array like this:

```
String[] s={"0010", "0110", "1010", "1110", "0001", "0011"}
```

I need to get each pairs of elements which changed inside array. In this case, only one element out of 4 gets changed for every string.

For the example:
for 0010, as the first position(0) change to 1 on 1010, I need to print out

> {"0010","1010"}

for 0001, as the third position(0) change to 1 on 0011, I need to print out

> {"0001", "0011"}

and so on.
Is there any way in java to get this result and how? Is this same to get string inside string array?

Comment: Are those supposed to be `String`s? As posted, your code line doesn't compile. Also, can you elaborate a bit, maybe show us what you have tried yourself?

Comment: That's not valid code to start with - 0010 isn't a string... It really helps if you provide a short but complete program which actually demonstrates the problem, rather than just describing it.

Comment: `String[] s={"0010", "0110","1010","1110"," 0001"," 0011"}` . I think this is the valid String Array

Comment: Ah yes, I'm forget "" while typing. I edited my question.

Comment: is this like only one element out of 4 gets changed ? please explain the precise defination for a set here.

Comment: yes, @anuraggupta, only one element out 4 gets changed. That's why I said a pair of elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String[] s={"0010", "0110", "1010", "1110", "0001", "0011"};
    for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<s.length;j++)
        {
            if(isPair(s[i].toCharArray(), s[j].toCharArray()))
            {
                System.out.println("{\""+s[i] + "\",\"" + s[j]+"\"}");
            }
        }
    }
}
public static boolean isPair(char[] a, char[] b)
{
    int count = 0;
    if(a.length == b.length)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        {
            if(a[i]!=b[i])
                count++;
        }
    }
    return count == 1 ? true : false;
}
}
```

Comment: Wow, it works! So I need to compare like this, I see. Thank you @anurag gupta